# Does quantum superposition enable the possibility of free will?

Tags: free-will, quantum-physics

I've been thinking about the problem of free will. In a deterministic universe, it seems like everything is just dominoes falling, one after the other. No room for choice.

But what about quantum mechanics and superposition. A particle can be in two states at once, until you measure it. And then it collapses into one state or the other.

Could something similar be happening in our brains? Could some internal processes in our bodies be in a state of superposition? Could the act of choosing be the thing that collapses these superpositions?

Imagine your brain is in a superposition of two states: A1 and B1. And let's say that action C1 is only possible if your brain is in state A1, while action D1 is only possible if your brain is in state B1.

Now, if you choose to do C1, does that mean you collapse your brain's superposition into state A1? And if you choose D1, do you collapse it into B1?

If so, could this be a way to have free will? A way for your choices to actually affect the physical state of your brain?

1. Is it possible that there are quantum superpositions in the brain, specifically in the processes involved in decision making?
2. If so, could the act of making a choice collapse these superpositions in the way I described?
3. Would this count as free will? Or is it just randomness masquerading as choice?

So, what do you think? Is there a quantum path to free will?

Comment: "randomness masquerading as choice" <- that.

Comment: @NotThatGuy "choice seen only as randomness" <- or that

Comment: Determinism isn't the only problem with free will. As per the comments above, in your case now the choice is simply coming from randomness/fuzziness, and is therefore still "externally influenced choice", not "totally _free_ choice"

Comment: Who's making the choice here?   That is to say,  what's the difference between "you" and "your brain"?  And why aren't "you" also subject to physical laws?

Comment: There's a few books on this question that a quick search using "quantum", "brain" and "consciousness" should turn up. The ones I've read are not entirely nonsense but also not entirely convincing. So it seems it's still an open question.

Comment: Roger Penrose is famous for invoking quantum processes as an explanation for free will and consciousness.

Comment: You can find different resources about this question in this forum. You can't prove determinism with finitism and neo-determinism with infinitism as shortly.

Comment: To elaborate on Joel Keene's point: If you and your brain are the same thing, and your decisions are determined by the matter (and interactions between bits of matter) happening in your brain, then your decisions are determined by you.

Comment: This seems related to the theory called Orch OR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction > Orchestrated objective reduction (Orch OR) is a theory which
> postulates that consciousness originates at the quantum level inside
> neurons, rather than the view that it is a product of connections
> between neurons.

Comment: I think part of what muddies the waters here is that the concept of “you” is ill defined. What would it even mean for “you” to decide things? It could be like thinking your next thought before thinking it. It seems either contradictory or meaningless

Comment: Are you not missing your own point?

In a deterministic universe, it seems like everything is just dominoes falling, one after the other. No room for choice.

On that level, what exactly changes with quantum mechanics and superposition?

On that level, what difference might it make that the particle settled into a single state only after being measured? How can you exclude that measurement from the fall of dominoes?

On that level, how is the particle even 'in' two states, rather than 'having an equal potential to be in' one of two?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin There are many things in the universe that cannot be proven, but we cannot accept this as absolute truth. How is it that in some cases we encounter 'reasons' for which we cannot demonstrate determinism? These are things that can broaden our horizons. I'm trying to be apolitical, but if we don't need free will, how long does this go on? Determinism is an unattainable goal in the matrix.

Comment: @fkybrd  Why direct that at me? How might your ideas relate to the Question here? 

What could usefully be meant by 'There are many things in the universe that cannot be proven, but we cannot accept this as absolute truth…'? How might that work in English?

Why might anyone mind whether you could demonstrate determinism? Such ideas might broaden your own horizons but how does 'our' come into this?

How might anything being apolitical relate to free will?

How could it matter whether determinism was attainable in the Matrix?

How long must you go on without a useful point?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Hawking devoted a significant part of his life to the "The Theory of Everything" and did not find it. Cantor also tried to prove "Cantor's Theorem" and it was shown that it was not possible to prove it with counter-theses. I have to be given such a key that I become a materialist. Because the indicators we use are all finite materials, and there is not infinitism with finite indicators. Things that are not within the scope of our observation cannot be said to be absolute reasons. This is the breaking point of the certainty of determinism. Your sensitivity should be accordingly.

Comment: How might what was not proved with counter-theses matter?

What might ‘I have to be given such a key that I become a materialist’ mean in English?

What might ‘Because the indicators we use are all finite materials, and there is not infinitism with finite indicators’ mean in English?

What might ‘Things that are not within the scope of our observation cannot be said to be absolute reasons’ mean in English?

What might ‘This is the breaking point of the certainty of determinism’ mean in English?

What might ‘Your sensitivity should be accordingly’ mean in English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to answer your question, but I'd also like to say some things regarding the nature of the question and how people's fascination with free will is more or less unfounded.

In short, yes, it's entirely possible. It actually coincides quite well with the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, which states that whenever a choice is made (or when a wavefunction collapses), a universe where a different choice was made branches off from our own, for every possible choice.

In terms of it being actual quantum mechanics, there have actually been some species of birds which have been found to use quantum entanglement to determine when and where to migrate. Nothing similar has been found yet in humans, but it's not implausible, and, at the electronic scale our brain signals work on, some would say it's more than likely.

And, as a third possible solution, it's possible that the quantum mechanical nature of reality is actually just how free will is physically encoded in our universe. The fundamental problem with free will is that it's typically taken to be some non-physical concept. However, maybe when the wavefunction of a particle collapses, it's the representation of a choice we've made (or have yet to make; time can be weird in quantum theory), and actually the "randomness" is just us making choices and the universe responding accordingly.

Ultimately, there are several ways in which what you're describing could be the case. However, I would argue that it actually doesn't matter. Let me explain:

Free will is an inherently non-scientific idea. It posits that there is some metaphysical force which influences how our choices are made. How could this ever be justified with science? Free will can't be physically observed, so proposing it in any theory of physics (or scientific theory in general) is kind of absurd. The cases I mentioned above are not physical observations of free will, but rather us interpreting physical observations as being manifestations of free will somehow. i.e., free will can never be observed, but instead only offered as an interpretation or "theory", more or less. So, just as with most metaphysical ideas (such as god), the existence of free will could never be proven nor disproven by science.

So what? whether or not free will exists, we, at the very least, have the illusion of choice, and this is enough to eliminate any practical difference between its existence or nonexistence. Truly, the only aspect of free will that actually effects our choices and lives is whether or not we believe in it. Believing in free will or determinism will change your outlook on the world which will in turn change how you make choices.

Because of this, I believe that we should simply not make a choice in whether or not free will exists. The belief either way is arbitrary, and ultimately unnecessary and unfounded. We should instead develop an outlook on life which is independent of any idea of free will, and not make a choice. If you're familiar with any formal or mathematical logic, it's akin to how the continuum hypothesis is independent of ZFC and whether or not its true is an arbitrary choice.

So, what you say may very well be the case, but it could never be shown to be true and could only be offered as an interpretation or explanation of what we do observe. Additionally, it doesn't and shouldn't matter whether free will exists or not. Instead, you should simply make the choice to not believe one way or the other.

Comment: "independent of any idea of free will" -- This can be difficult because concepts like responsibility and justice, and good vs. evil, are based on the assumption of free will. If the criminal didn't *choose* to commit the crime, it would be unfair to punish them for it.

Comment: @Barmar On the other hand, if one were to believe in determinism, then a person's actions are solely a product of their upbringing. Punishment wouldn't make sense in that case, and instead implies that criminals should only be subject to rehabilitation. In line with my answer, and choosing to ignore the implications of a belief in free will, I would instead rely on the humanitarian studies that show that rehabilitation is usually better for society, and I think that that's a much more solid justification than an approach from a belief in free will or determinism.

Comment: While it's not a totally deterministic philosophy, progressive attitudes towards criminal justice have allowed for many more defenses based on influences outside the perpetrator's control. "twinkie defeneses", temporary insanity based on PTSD, etc.

Comment: I don't know how to turn it into an answer, but my general feeling is that free will is an emergent phenomenon. So even if the universe is deterministic, there's enough chaos that we can't predict complex actions of organisms.

Comment: @Barmar In your scenario, the persons imposing punishment would not be choosing to do so, either.

Comment: @sdenham It's chaotic turtles all the way down.

Comment: Even if we do not believe, the criminal *chose* to commit a crime, we can still collectively decide to pretend free will "exists" and that we punish individuals for, what looks like to be, "their" actions

Answer (score 14):

The question assumes an incompatibilist view of free will, and then rests their notion of free will on the possibility of true quantum randomness. Two notes on that:

1. Quantum mechanics may or may not be fundamentally, genuinely random. That's up to interpretation, and the jury is out among experts.
2. Let's imagine you find the randomness you're looking for in QM -- then what? What have you gained?

You can now prove a part of your decision making process in your brain is random, and that makes you free? If a decision you're making is going to change depending on if an electron in your brain goes right instead of left, and that's decided by a random quantum process which *crucially* YOU don't control, then you haven't gained freedom - you're now a slave to randomness. Is being a slave to randomness any better than being a slave to determinism?

Comment: One should not conflate *not predetermined* with *out of my control*.  Random in the sense of the first does not lead to the second.

Comment: @NikosM. Do you believe humans have control over quantum events?

Comment: Why do I have to believe that in order to say what I said? As my answer notes, usually libertarianism takes free will as a basic process by itself not necessarily reduced to other processes.

Comment: This is a thread about the idea of free will being rooted in quantum randomness. If that's not the idea of free will you're talking about, I'm concerned you may be having an out-of-place conversation. @NikosM.

Comment: As my answer also notes some authors do propose quantum models of free will, although this is not necessary and undetermined does not mean incompatible with choice.

Comment: the question is not suggesting that the brain directly chooses which state to collapse into. Rather, it's proposing that the brain's superposition states constrain which actions are possible, and by choosing a specific action, you indirectly force the brain's superposition to collapse in a particular way to maintain logical consistency. In this model, the action selection comes first, and the collapse of the brain state is a consequence of that choice, not the other way around.

Comment: @Gush so if quantum randomness is not part of the *cause* of the choice, then what use is it for explaining free will at all? If something other than quantum randomness is deciding stuff, then... it doesn't seem like quantum randomness is helping us understand choice at all. It isn't doing any work. Where do you suppose the choice comes from? Does it come from somewhere else in the brain? Does it come from an immaterial mind or soul?

Comment: @TKoL -- It is a bit of an overstatement to say that randomness is in dispute.  I don't think any of the alternatives deny the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, which by itself makes any "predictive demon" thinking invalid, and that is the framework meant by a deterministic universe.  And the two surveys of physicists I have seen had Copenhagen at 50-60%, MWI at 15-25%, Bohm at 5%,  and other alternatives none exceeding 2%, and not repeatably measurable in both surveys.

Comment: Of the three appreciably supported models, only Bohm is determinist (MWI puts the randomness in what one will subsequently observe), and is a different theory (called Bohmian mechanics) which is testable vs. QM.  5% vs 75% is not quite "consensus", but is close enough that those outside theoretical physics can treat QM as random.  That is why cosmology models use the random versions of QM.

Comment: @Dcleve MWI is only subjectively random, it's meta-deterministic

Comment: TKol -- all observations are subjective, and that is the only data we have.  Saying that it is only subjectively random, is not a relevant modifier. One can see that it is probabilistic because it makes identical predictions to Copenhagen, and Copenhagen is probabilistic.     MWI has other problems too, it is predictively useless, "all of the above" is not a prediction, and it is not testable in principle.  It fails both Popper's falsifiability criteria, and his version of Occam (most useful theory is the one that excludes the most possibilities).

Comment: @Dcleve I disagree with almost everything you said there, but I'm too lazy to talk about why. Hope you're having a good day anyway.

Comment: @TKoL -  
I agree with you - if i am understanding you correctly that:

If we say the collapse into a particular state was purely random or determined by some other physical process, then it seems the choice was ultimately determined by this random or deterministic collapse, not by any free will of the agent 
On the other hand - if the choice is causing the quantum state of the brain to collapse in a way that's consistent with that choice, we leave open the question of where the choice came from in the first place.

Comment: @Gush and if you're leaving open the question of where the choice came from in the first place, then it seems like QM hasn't helped you build a model of choice. Usually, the point people try to make in bringin up QM is as *part of the causal process of making a choice*. If it's not part of that process, then QM is as relevant to free will philosophically as newtonian physics is.

Answer (score 11):

No, quantum superposition isn't really a plausible explanation, since processes in the brain seem to be macroscopic (ie they involve combinations of neurons which collectively contain oodles of quantum particles), and the brain itself is a warm, noisy environment from a quantum physics perspective, so it seems unlikely that the kind of weird effects that are popularly associated with quantum mechanics could account for free will.

As an aside, all quantum states can be expressed as superpositions of other states, so particles are never not in some form of superposition of other.

Comment: Possibly the OP means "mixture of states" instead of "superposition"? - Ceterum censeo: To explain free will with quantum indeterminacy is ruled out - you recall the reason. And the subjective feeling of free choice is the contrary of randomness.

Comment: There are actually species of birds that have been found to use quantum entanglement to help their brains determine when and where to migrate. It's opened up a whole new field of study called Quantum Biology. So, while we haven't found anything like that yet in humans, it's not entirely implausible.

Comment: Chaos studies have shown many macro-scale systems are chaotic, such that QM indeterminacy can be leveraged up to macro scale consequences.  All living things are such bounded chaotic systems, where a single QM event can have dramatic consequences for us.  The "Schoedinger's cat" thought problem is an illustration of such macro-scale leveraging.  Our brain states are chaotically under stable, so the possibility of QM effects having consequences on future brin states is highly plausible.   Consider the effect of a single gamma ray causing cancer in a person, that will affect their thoughts!

Comment: @Dcleve no, the Schrodinger's cat thought experiment is an illustration that extrapolating quantum concepts to everyday objects yields nonsense. That was Schrodinger's point is suggesting it.

Comment: Hmm. That's not how the thought experiment was used in my physics classes.  The principle works out fine -- a detector can sense a single decay, and leverage up macro-scale consequences.  It is an illustration of a hair-trigger bounded chaotic system at macro scale.    How to interpret this in QM theory -- is more problematic.  The role of observer in collapsing QM events is suspect, as the cat is an observer, and "observer" versions of QM interpretation may need revision.

Comment: @MarcoOcram "extrapolating quantum concepts to everyday objects yields nonsense"? Really? Current mainstream physics holds that, apart from gravity, essentially all behavior of "everyday objects" is rooted in QM, mostly the behavior of electrons and photons. And, consider that the retina of the human eye can detect single photons, so not only in the lab, but in the brain, atomic level events manifest macroscopically. These prove, conclusively, that the idea that the macroscopic world is fundamentally different from the QM world, is a fallacy.

Comment: @addlai clearly we are made of particles that obey QM, so in that sense you are right, but cats are not simultaneously alive and dead, so in that sense you are wrong.

Comment: @DrCleve, chaos is not a good foundation of will, free or not.

Comment: @Marco Ocram "but cats are not ..." according to ... your hunch? Human intuition about the nature of physical reality, isn't worth much. If the history of physics and math hasn't taught you that by now, not sure what to say. So if we can easily set up an apparatus to make the cat's life dependent on a subatomic "quantum" superposed event, but you don't believe the physics applies to the cat the same way, but can't explain why, do you really believe you have a solid argument that quantum physics excludes free will? I can't see that you have presented any argument at all.

Comment: @Addlai I am afraid you are so wrong that no amount of exchanges in comments will get us to the same place! Either that or we are arguing at cross purposes.

Comment: @Marco Ocram You haven't stated what I'm supposedly wrong about, or why, and your comments suggest you are not too familiar with the significance of the Schrodinger's Cat thought experiment.  If you have something new to say about it, to definitively resolve what to make of it, by all means, stop writing comments here and publish a paper for the world, advancing the state of physics and philosophy. Otherwise, you might start by reading the appropriate section from any introductory book on QM, or the Wikipedia article on it.

Comment: @Addlai many thanks for the helpful suggestions. I have a PhD in quantum theory, so I'll skip the introductory books.

Answer (score 3):

One cent.

Libertarian free will requires negation of determinism. So indeterminism at the level of basic physics is a bonus point for libertarianism.

However, it is not required that free will functions in a quantum mechanical sense. **It can as well be a basic process by itself**, not reduced to other more basic processes.

Libertarianism usually takes free will as something of a basic process by itself.

That being said, there are indeed authors who use quantum mechanical models of free will in their arguments (see some online references..).

Furthermore the Free Will Theorem states that if one entity can have free will, then given the quantum nature of the universe, other entities can have it as well. So in a sense the quantum nature of reality can play a role.

PS: I cannot rule out quantum models of free will neither in principle nor via physical/neural arguments. Indeterminism (such that is suitable for choice) *can* manifest as a result of quantum mechanics, even if the brain/body is seen as purely macroscopic, because, for example, existing non-linearities can make the micro indeterminism relevant even at these macro scales (leaving aside purely quantum effects which are manifest even at macro scales and concepts like "quantum holism").

PS2: A state which is compatible with more than one future outcome (a "superposition" state) is a plausible model of free will and this state need not directly be related to quantum mechanics, as noted above, it can be formed with many other ways. Various areas can exhibit features similar and/or common to those peculiarly manifest in quantum mechanics. Finally, one should not conflate "*not predetermined*" with "*out of my control*", random in the sense of the first does not lead to the second.

Some references:

1. [Quantum Free Will Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604079)
2. [Quantum Indeterminism, Free Will, and Self-Causation](https://philarchive.org/rec/MASRAT-5)
3. [A Quantum Model of Non-illusory Free Will](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-21908-6_7)
4. [Quantum Approaches to Consciousness and Free Will, SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-consciousness/)

Answer (score 2):

This whole subject is fraught with pitfalls. There are two dual issues, both of which are very slippery: 1. To what extent is our understanding of the relevant physics good enough to make definite conclusions, 2. To what extent can we pin down what we mean by free will.

I'll throw in a third issue as well: 3. What we know from the history of mathematics, is that even where our definitions and assumptions are quite rigorous, even the hunches of the best mathematicians are sometimes dead wrong. I'm a bit of a chauvinist here; if you haven't worked in math, or thought pretty deeply about it, you probably don't really know how easy it is to be dead wrong about something that seems clear to you. I'd put a lot of theoretical physicists in this category, by the way. Many of them seem to
thrive on public attention, writing popular books, and working with media producers, making exciting pronouncements about the world, with what is very likely unwarranted confidence.

As for 1., physics has taught us so far: a) our naive assumptions about the nature of the physical world, if there even is such a world, are quite unreliable, b) current theories in physics are incomplete, and known to be inconsistent, and therefore somewhat wrong at best, totally wrong at worst.

Despite this, many people argue with what I think is unwarranted confidence, as if they "know", at least roughly, how the future of physics going to work out. It's maybe a century or so that we've been able to explain why the sun is hot. Before that, we could easily argue, seemingly quite solidly, that no such thing as the sun could exist. A very detailed calculation of how much chemical energy the sun could possibly contain, could have been phrased in very technical, science-y terms, proving that the sun is a mere fiction. Yet, somehow, it always did seem to shine up there and give warmth. I have the same sense of these subjective experiences, like consciousness and free will. You can make an erudite argument why they can't exist based on crude arguments from physics know to be wrong ... yet ... there they are.

For this reason, I am unconvinced by arguments along the lines of "X can't be true, because physical theory Y contradicts it". In this category, I put arguments about what is supposedly impossible about the physical brain, an organ about which we have much to learn. In particular, there's a slowly growing list of biological phenomena believed to be "quantum" in nature, including photosynthesis, the sense of smell, and the navigational sense of migratory birds, among others. If you think you "know" what can and can't happen inside an organ we don't understand, built out of biology that only gets more surprising and more complex the closer we look, because of physical theories known to be wrong, I'd caution not to take yourself too very seriously.

The second issue, is even more troublesome. Verbal definitions can express certain kinds of logical relationships. My hunch is that phenomena like free will, are outside its expressive capabilities. Give me the precise definition of free will. I haven't seen such a definition so far. The same problem vexes such basic questions as "What is energy?", "What is matter?", "What is a force?", "What is a measurement?", "What is an action?", "What is the relationship between a physical law and the physical world?" Etc. We don't even have a stab in the dark at these things, as far as I'm aware.

And ... if we don't have something like free will, we don't really have science as most people understand it, because we can't do an experiment in any real sense. The scientist in the lab is just a bunch of matter bouncing around, their though processes are a bunch of matter bouncing around, and it's trivial to construct theoretical universes where the scientific theories of such bouncing around matter, are totally inconsistent with the actual workings of the universe they are in.

Answer (score 1):

No, the one does not seem correlated to the other.

"Free will" means that if we would rewind the universe to a point in time before a choice I made, *perfectly*, then I would be able to take a different choice next time.

"Quantum" means that choices might be random.

If people say that there is no free will, they do not mean that all future decisions can be known beforehand; i.e. it is perfectly possible that there is no free will, but the "quantum conjecture" from your argument is true at the same time. This would mean that when rewinding the universe, my decision *could* be different the next time around; but it would not make "me" (whatever that is) more in control of the decision, it would just be attributed to the randomness of that one "q-bit" falling the other way.

For free-will proponents, this quantum argument would be even worse! It would mean that choices are inherently random; and free will is probably the farthest away from randomness as you could want something to be.

So, TLDR: there might or might not be quantum effects introducing randomness in our brain (and heck, there could very well be non-quantum macro effects which introduce randomness - for example a random high-energy particle from outer space hitting one of your neurons just so, influencing a decision). *If* quantum superposition has a major influence in our decisions, then it would not influence the question of free will at all, very likely, or make it even less probable.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the question is unanswerable on its own terms – when we speak of "free will", we're discussing the freedom of what you might call a "soul" or "mind" or some other metaphysical object which *by definition* does not exist within (any) physics.

If your mind can be fully explained by a theory consistent with the observed world – i.e. by science – then by definition you are not free to make choices inconsistent with that theory.  If the theory is deterministic, then your choices are decided at the beginning of time, and if it's non-deterministic, they're decided by the roll of a dice on the day, but either way it's physics that decides them.

(You might want to say that a dice roll could be influenced from some higher plane, but that's just saying it's not random after all).

However, just because science doesn't admit (let alone justify) a concept of "free will", this doesn't mean morality doesn't exist.  Skeletor isn't excused by the fact that he's written evil, and our responsibility for our actions isn't diminished by the role of physical processes, even if it amounts to 100%.

### To butcher Daniel Dennett's position:

Yes, your choices are the result of (practically) random events, but the decision to murder or not murder someone doesn't come down to a *single* dice roll in the moment.  It is the sum of *all* the dice rolls that ever happened to make you you.  That unique and irreproducible set of circumstances is who you are, and so whatever it leads to is what you decided.

Answer (score 0):

Deep conceptual issues need to be untangled before attempting a quantum explanation of free choice

**The Measurement Problem**: How does measurement collapse the quantum wavefunction into definite states, and what constitutes a "measurement"?

**Quantum-to-Classical Transition**: How do quantum phenomena at the microscopic level manifest in the macroscopic classical world relevant to human cognition and agency?

**Nature of Quantum Randomness**: Is the apparent randomness in QM truly fundamental or due to hidden variables? Is it ontic or epistemic?

**Compatibility with Determinism**: Is free will compatible with a deterministic universe (compatibilism) or does it require genuine indeterminism (incompatibilism)?

**Mind-Matter Relation**: For QM brain processes to influence free will, consciousness must be related to material brain states, not e.g. epiphenomenal.

Answer (score -3):

First: The Universe is **not** deterministic. Determinism is only a  *simplified* *model* of the physical reality, a model used only in classical physics.

Second: Free will, as the ability to make decisions, has nothing to do with physics. Decision-making does not involve any exhanges of matter or energy or any causal chains of events. Decision-making is purely a mental process where knowledge, desires, needs, imagination, emotions, opinions, beliefs, etc. interact to generate new knowledge about future actions.

Comment: "*Decision-making does not involve any exhanges of matter or energy..*" very well put

Comment: The brain alone consumes 20% of a person's metabolic energy. To say that any mental process, decision-making or otherwise, doesn't involve exchanges of matter or energy is only true if you reject materialism a priori. If you're doing that, all right, but you should probably make that more explicit in your answer.

Comment: The truth of a statement does not depend on what philosophy I accept or reject. Mental processes are not physical processes and that is a hard fact, not a philosophical standpoint.